# Add spaces between 2 strings

Tags: java, string

How do format it in such a way that it prints both strings(string1 & string2) with spaces that vary according to the length of string1?

Say I want the max space between the 2 strings to be 10white space.

```
<Title>"10whitespace"<Title2>
<String1>            <String2>
```

Where `title1` & `title2` is a fixed string. I need both `string1` and `string2` to always be below of the said title

Comment: Problem here. [W] vs [ ]... Their width depends on what character it is. This kinda makes it impossible if you're using a normal CMD or so.

Comment: Have a look at [String formatters.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: Also try [Apache Commons' StringUtils.rightPad()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#rightPad%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: What are you writing to? The console? a File? a GUI component, such as JTextField?  A web page? The solution(if it is possible) will depend on where you are writing.